# Xbox One Introduction Video

Tags: xbox-one

When I got my Xbox One at Christmas in 2015. I did the setup then afterwards, there was a video. It was "The Greatest Games Lineup in Xbox History", And I have been looking for this video for a long time. Is there any way I can re-watch it?

Comment: [One of these](https://www.google.nl/search?q=The+Greatest+Games+Lineup+in+Xbox+History&oq=The+Greatest+Games+Lineup+in+Xbox+History&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.223j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=The+Greatest+Games+Lineup+in+Xbox+History&safe=off&tbm=vid)?

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LS-h_oTP1k) the video you're looking for? It's a short, intro-length video titled "The Greatest Games Lineup in Xbox History (15 sec)".

Comment: No, it played after the first setup. But there are two of them. I am looking for the most recent one that played for me on Christmas. There are no videos of it that I have found. And I would be very grateful if you found a way for me to replay it on the Xbox One itself somehow, Or if you could find a video somewhere of it.